# Error while passing object to controller with ajax mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having object before any changes on his propoeries

```
var beforeChangeUser = {
     "Id": row.userId,
     "Name": row.name,
     "Surname": row.surname,
     "Rate": row.rate,
     "AccName": row.accName,
     "FixCosts": row.fixCosts,
    }
```

There is user which may have been changed some propoerties

```
 var changedUser = {
       "Id": row.userId,
       "Name": $('#nameEdit').val(),
       "Surname": $('#surnameEdit').val(),
       "Rate": $('#rateEdit').val(),
       "AccName": $('#accountEdit').val(),
       "FixCosts": $('#fixCostsEdit').val(),
      }
```

I am comparing those two ojects to check if any changes was made

```
function getDiffrences(beforeChangeUser, changedUser) {
    var user = changedUser;
    var changed = false;
    if (beforeChangeUser.Name !== changedUser.Name) {
        user.Name = changedUser.Name;
        changed = true;
    }
    if (beforeChangeUser.Surname !== changedUser.Surname) {
        user.Surname = changedUser.Surname;
        changed = true;
    }
    if (beforeChangeUser.Rate !== changedUser.Rate) {
        user.Rate = changedUser.Rate;
        changed = true;
    }
    if (beforeChangeUser.AccName !== changedUser.AccName) {
        user.AccName = changedUser.AccName;
        changed = true;
    }
    if (beforeChangeUser.FixCosts !== changedUser.FixCosts) {
        user.FixCosts = changedUser.FixCosts;
        changed = true;
    }
    if (changed) {
        return user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally there is ajax which I am trying to send data to

```
var userToChange = getDiffrences(beforeChangeUser, changedUser);
                                    if (userToChange == false) {
                                        errorMsg.text("You did not make any changes");
                                    } else {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: '/ManageUsersController/EditUser',
                                            data: userToChange,
                                            success: function (succ) {

                                            },
                                            error: function (data) {
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
```

I am sending it to controller as below

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult EditUser(UserEditViewModel userToChange)
    {
        return Json(_userService.EditUser(new UserEditDTO
        {
            AccName = userToChange.AccName,
            FixCosts = userToChange.FixCosts,
            Id = Int32.Parse(userToChange.Id),
            Name = userToChange.Name,
            Rate = userToChange.Rate,
            Surname = userToChange.Surname,
        }));
    }
```

I am getting error 404 not found /ManageUsersController/EditUser

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: change `url: '/ManageUsersController/EditUser',` to `url: '/ManageUsers/EditUser',`

Comment: Or Use  url:'@Url.Action("EditUser","ManageUsersController")'